# How to reproduce a loop "for" to fill a data frame from another data frame using "dplyr"?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am searching for a fast way to fill a data frame from another data frame. To do this, I would like to use the `dplyr` package. For example, consider the following code that replaces NAs in `dt2` from `dt1`. My objective is to avoid the loop `for`.

```
set.seed(123)
  dt1 <- data.frame(ID = c(104, 109, 111, 121), a = c(1, 8, 5, 9), b = c(100, 220, 877, 120), c = c(1, 3, 2, 3))
  ## print(dt1)
  dt2 <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(104, 1), rep(109, 3), rep(111, 2), rep(121, 3)), 
                    a = c(rep(NA, 1), rep(NA, 3), rep(NA, 2), rep(NA, 3)),
                    b = c(rep(NA, 1), rep(NA, 3), rep(NA, 2), rep(NA, 3)))
  ## print(dt2)

  for(i in as.vector(dt1[,c("ID")])) {

    dt2[dt2[, c("ID")] %in% i, c("a")] <- sample(0:dt1[dt1[, c("ID")] == i, c("a")], size = dt1[dt1[, c("ID")] == i, c("c")], replace = T)
    dt2[dt2[, c("ID")] %in% i, c("b")] <- sample(0:dt1[dt1[, c("ID")] == i, c("b")], size = dt1[dt1[, c("ID")] == i, c("c")], replace = T)

  }
  print(dt2)
```

The output is:

```
>   print(dt2)
   ID a   b
1 104 0  79
2 109 3  10
3 109 7 116
4 109 8 197
5 111 3 840
6 111 2 398
7 121 6 108
8 121 5  29
9 121 1   5
```

Here is my first test using the `dplyr` package:

```
  set.seed(123)
  dt1 <- data.frame(ID = c(104, 109, 111, 121), a = c(1, 8, 5, 9), b = c(100, 220, 877, 120), c = c(1, 3, 2, 3))
  ## print(dt1)
  dt2 <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(104, 1), rep(109, 3), rep(111, 2), rep(121, 3)), 
                    a = c(rep(NA, 1), rep(NA, 3), rep(NA, 2), rep(NA, 3)),
                    b = c(rep(NA, 1), rep(NA, 3), rep(NA, 2), rep(NA, 3)))
  i <- 104
  test <- dt2 %>%
    mutate(a = replace(a, ID == i, sample(0:dt1[dt1[, c("ID")] == i, c("a")], size = dt1[dt1[, c("ID")] == i, c("c")], replace = T)),
           b = replace(b, ID == i, sample(0:dt1[dt1[, c("ID")] == i, c("b")], size = dt1[dt1[, c("ID")] == i, c("c")], replace = T)))
  print(test)
```

However, I don’t know how to consider the loop on `ID`, `i.e., with i = 104, i = 109, i = 111, and i = 121`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this using a `left_join` with 'dt1' by 'ID', then grouped by 'ID', `transmute` the 'a' and 'b' columnns

```
left_join(dt2[1], dt1, by = "ID") %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    transmute(a = sample(0:a[1], size = c[1], replace = TRUE),
              b = sample(0:b[1], size = c[1], replace = TRUE))
```

---

It can also done from 'df1'

```
dt1 %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate_at(vars(a, b), funs(list(sample(0:., size = c, replace = TRUE)))) %>%
    unnest %>%
    select(-c)
```

Comment: Note that if we want to exactly match the seed value, you may need to add `set.seed` i.e. `left_join(dt2[1], dt1, by = "ID") %>% 
    
    group_by(ID) %>% 
 do({set.seed(123)
  data.frame(.) %>% transmute(a = sample(0:a[1], size = c[1], replace = TRUE), b = sample(0:b[1], size = c[1], replace = TRUE))})`